# How to fake output to automate UI actions on headless server?

Tags: python, linux, selenium, ui-automation

Couldn’t think of a solution yet.
I have a scraper running currently. In the first 80% of one loop (every 3-4 hours), the entire process can be run in a headless server without any output needed as it uses Selenium and BS4.

However for the rest of the remaining 20%, I could not program some clicking and typing actions with Selenium for that specific website. I am assuming that it is because the single page website has many many frames (I might be wrong.)
So, to combat this and to get around it, I basically used PyAutoGui to control my mouse and click and enter things in textfields repeatedly. I did this by specifying coordinates for each button.

How can I do this on Ubuntu 18.04(the server) but without a monitor? Is there a way to fake a monitor of a certain resolution so the coordinates I select when the server is plugged into a monitor of resolution xxx,yyy still works exactly without issue when i create a fake output of resolution xxx,yyy
I have an extra monitor but I don’t want it to be running all night and day and letting snooping eyes see (i live in a shared house).
Thanks

EDIT: I reread this after posting it and sorry if the text seems messy im very tired.
What i mean is that the places where the mouse is supposed to click are determined by coordinates relative to ur monitor. How can i replicate this if the monitor is unplugged?
Sorry again

Comment: Probably best then search instead for frames and elements, rather than coordinates

Comment: You probably already use some virtual X server or similar? In this case you could connect to the virtual X server using a VNC tool or a similar remote desktop tool...

Answer (score 0):

No software solution, but you could use a "hdmi dummy" with your current resolution. It emulates a display, so your computer will work like usually.